Why is a penny called a "win"?
I've just found out that a penny can be called a win in slang. It appears to be only used in British slang, and perhaps in Irish too.
Green’s Dictionary of Slang mentions below and gives the earliest citation from 1535:

win n. 
also winn, wyn 
[origin unknown, but Vaux suggests, without further explanation, an abbr. of Winchester; Ribton-Turner, A History of Vagrants (1887), suggests synon. Erse pinghin, Manx ping]
1. a penny. 
c.1535 [UK] R. Copland Hye way to the Spyttel House Eiii: For the bene bonse my watch hath a wyn.

However, GDoS also offers a second meaning in US English as 'cent':

2. (US) a cent (cf. penny n. (1)).
1859  [US]    Matsell Vocabulum 96: win A cent.

If 'win' is an abbreviation of Winchester, how so? If not, why might it be referred to as 'win'? Could it be related to winning money, winnings?
Note: OED also states the same for the origin: "Origin obscure; quot. 1819 suggests that it may be short for Winchester." OED does not state that the word is obsolete.

A penny could be called a win; it appears that this bit of slang is long since obsolete.

@KateBunting OED and other dictionaries do not say that it is obsolete. OED normally states when a word is obsolete. Perhaps dialectal or jargon? Or out of use in general parlance? There can be an explanation for the US usage as well.

I based my comment on the fact that Green's latest  example is from 1881 and that I have never heard of it in my (fairly wide) reading.

Fair point. OED gives the sense of "Gain, acquisition, profit; also, advantage, benefit." for the noun  win as obsolete, but not for the sense of "a penny". OED's latest citation for this sense is from 1900. Perhaps it fell out of use but not completely. It is harder to find written evidence for slang.

@KateBunting I agree in 75 years of reading I've never heard this usage. I suggest that the dictionary not tagging it as obsolete is an oversite.

@PeterJennings You've heard it now. You are welcome :)

It seems unlikely that it would be related to winning, because I don't think you would use that for the smallest denomination. Maybe there was once a penny coin that had an image of someone named Winchester (analogous to the way "Benjamin" became slang for $100 bills), or he was a coin-maker.

"OED gives the sense of 'gain, acquisition, [etc.]' as obsolete": that "obsolete" is obsolete as this sense has returned to common use.  Which edition of the OED are you using?  If it is the first, that could account for "win" as "cent" not being marked obsolete.

@PeterJennings perhaps it was not yet obsolete in 1928 when the W entries were first published or at whatever earlier time the entry for "win" was finalized before publication.

@phoog OED later adds this non-obsolete sense for the noun win: "A gain; plural gains, winnings. colloquial." I believe the word winnings is the more common one for this sense.

@phoog OED says that "win, n.³ was last modified in December 2023." in entry history. This is the entry for the noun win of the sense "a penny" in slang.

"winnings" may be more common in some contexts, but you can't use it in the singular, and "win" is certainly common enough lately.  See for example https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+big+win+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3 -- if someone actually looked at that entry in December 2023 and didn't think to mark it obsolete then it is indeed an oversight as @PeterJennings suggests.

@phoog I’ve personally contacted the OED team about this and am awaiting their response also.

This answer is much helped by the many comments on the OP's question that triggered a memory "wasn't there a mint at Winchester?".
A search for "Royal mint Winchester" brings up this information from the Hampshire Cultural Trust website

For three hundred and fifty years Winchester had its own mint striking
coins under royal control. The first coins to carry the mint-signature
of Winchester (ǷIN or ǷINC - The Anglo-Saxon wen, or Ƿ, being
equivalent to the modern W) were issued at the very end of Alfred's
reign probably around 895. The mint's final period of activity was in
1248-50 during the reign of Henry III.

So coins minted at Winchester had "Win" stamped in their design and would almost certainly be called "a win".

We have a winner!

So why would penny be called a win, unless only pennies were minted in Winchester?

@WeatherVane I can only speculate. They only struck pennies (unlikely). It was a the most common coin (possibly). It was a hangover from when more coins were called "win". Other coins had different nicknames.

Win-win! It took us on a journey through history.

Win, meaning 'a penny' (or 'an old penny'), seems to have been primarily used in Scouse (Liverpool English) but has since fallen out of use. It may still persist as dialectal slang. Here is the entry for win from the book The Liverpool English Dictionary: A Record of the Language of Liverpool 1850–2015 by Tony Crowley:

Win (n.): a penny. "Win", penny' (Jones 1935:5). 'The use of "meg" for halfpenny and "win" for penny, seems to be dying out' (Farrell 1950b: 4). "Fudge" for a farthing, "meg" for a half-penny and "win" for a penny are no longer current coin' (Whittington-Egan 1955a: 6). "Fudge" for a farthing, "meg" for a half-penny and "win" for a penny ... flourished in the [18]80s and [18]90s' (Jones 1955: 4). 'Win. One old penny (1d). Liverpool' (Howarth 1985: n.p.). Recorded from 1.16c.; derivation unclear.

The Routledge Dictionary of Historical Slang (by Eric Partridge) mentions the use of win in late 19th and 20th century in Ireland and hence U.S:

win, wing, winn, whin(n) 
*, but gen. the first or the third. A penny: c. (-1567): resp. C.17-20, late C.19–20 (mostly in Ireland and hence U.S.), C.17-20, C.19-20. Harman, Dekker, B.E., Grose, Vaux (Winchesten by 1900), 'Jon Bee' (who defines as a half-penny), H., Flynt (wing). Perhaps abbr. Winchester. 2. (win, and for senses 3, 4.) A victory: (sports and games) coll: from ca 1860. 3. A gain; gen. pl, (mostly monetary) gains: coll: from ca 1890. Perhaps abbr. winning(s).

